# PySpark (Step/Job) on EMR cannot connect to AWS Glue Data Catalog but Zeppelin can

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have setup an EMR cluster with Data Catalog enabled

[image]

I can access the data catalog when I use Zeppelin, but with jobs/steps I submit like:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXXX --steps "Type=spark,Name=Test,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,--conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false,--num-executors,2,--executor-cores,2,--executor-memory,8g,s3://XXXXXX/emr-test.py],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE"
```

I cannot see my data catalog when I use `spark.sql("USE xxx")` OR `spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES")` why is that.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Test") \
    .config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sql("USE ...")
spark.sql("SHOW TABLES").show()
spark.sql("SELECT querydatetime FROM flights LIMIT 10").show(10)

sc.stop()
```

I get something like:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Database 'xxxxxx' not found;"
```

Comment: Can we check in spark driver logs for any Glue related Access Exception? I have seen this error when the Spark Application does not have sufficient privileges to access Glue catalog

Comment: @DaRkMaN, I found out the problem is I am missing one line: `.enableHiveSupport()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out from https://michael.ransley.co/2018/08/28/spark-glue.html that

> To access the tables from within a Spark step you need to instantiate the spark session with the glue catalog:
>
> ```
> spark = SparkSession.builder \
>     .appName(job_name) \
>     .config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory") \
>     .enableHiveSupport() \
>     .getOrCreate()
> spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase("mydatabase")
> ```

I am missing the line `.enableHiveSupport()`. Its quite unfortunate this does not seem to be documented in the official docs ...